# How fixed npm that npm problem while installing Vue-cli?

Tags: npm, vue.js

I have got a problem with Vue/Cli instalation.

node: v8.11.3
npm : 6.4.1
os: MacOS 10.13.6

I executed the following command:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

and the errors :
[image]

Comment: you've probably installed node as sudo
look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Comment: @dcohenb :
thanks, I make steps for reinstall nodejs . Now my problem looks like on the screen : https://i.imgur.com/LeCqlFK.png

Comment: I recommend reinstalling Node with `nvm` or [`tj/n`](https://github.com/tj/n), which don't exhibit permission issues when installing packages.